Fixing Binary Execution Errors with Supervisor in Alpine Image
I am using alpine image, but I am getting errors when supervisors execute binary files. I am attaching an error along with the Dockerfile.
What thing do I need to change, and how do I correct it? Along with reason.
log 1
log 2
Here is the content of Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Build the Rust application
FROM rust:latest AS builder

# Install necessary dependencies (supervisord and others)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /V4.1

# Copy the source code
COPY . .

# Build the Rust application (assuming it's in /redis_stream directory)
WORKDIR /V4.1/redis_stream
RUN cargo build --release

# Stage 2: Create a minimal production image with newer GLIBC
FROM alpine:latest
# Install Supervisor and Redis
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
# RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor supervisor bash
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache supervisor libc6-compat bash
# RUN apk add gcompat

# Copy the built binary from the builder stage
WORKDIR /V4.1
COPY --from=builder /V4.1/redis_stream/target/release/consumer . 

RUN chmod +x /V4.1/consumer

# Copy the Supervisor config
COPY supervisord_docker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Copy the Redis config (optional)
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

COPY redis_stream/config.yml .

# Use Supervisor to manage Redis and your Rust application
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]




Content only available behind a link doesn't count towards satisfying [mre] rules. Make sure you're including everything necessary to answer (or determine if an answer is correct) inside the text of the question itself; that particularly includes error messages. Most of the time we'll be able to tell from the immediate error what else we need (be that output from running ldd or file against the executable, or otherwise), making full logs overkill.

(BTW, did you check whether you can run the same executable without supervisor within the same container? If you haven't, then we don't yet know if it's appropriate for supervisor to be part of the question scope at all -- the most common causes of this kind of failure on alpine will happen for any kind of execution, with or without supervisor).
